# Align many multiline equations

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I am struggling trying to align a set of equations of very different lengths. All equations shell be aligned to the comma between the formula and the variable declaration.

Despite the use of `split`, formula 3 is still too long. If I do another line break between `\left(` and `\right)`, I get an error `"Extra }, or forgotten right"`.

As soon as the splitting is done, I would like to arrange the first line of such a multiline formula left aligned, the next lines left aligned with a small skip in front, and only the last line right aligned to the comma. Is there a possibility to do this? Or any other sugesstions of presenting many of such long formulas together in one environment in a pretty way?

I found solutions for arranging one long formula in many lines OR to arrange many formulas together around a comma or something else OR to leftalign one formula like I described (`mathtools`' `\MoveEqLeft`), but I have no idea how to do all at the same time.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1} 
        \leq h_i 
        \leq \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_k 
             + \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} \bar{s}_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1}
    & ,     i \in \mathcal{I}_{21}
    \label{eq_1} \\
%
    \begin{split}
        \sum_{l=K_{21}+1}^{K_{22}} \alpha_{lk} (s_{il} + \bar{s}_{il}) \left( 1 + \varepsilon \right) 
            + w_i + \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2} \alpha_{ji} (s_{jk} + \bar{s}_{jk}) w_j
    &   \\
        \geq (1 + \varepsilon)(1-s_{ik}-\bar{s}_{ik})
    & ,  i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in \mathcal{K}_{22}
    \end{split} 
    \label{eq_2} \\
%
    \begin{split}   
        \left( 1- \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2}\alpha_{ji}t_{jk}\right) 
            \cdot \left( w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon -|w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon|\right) \cdot  \ldots 
        & \\
        \ldots \cdot \left( h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon - 
        | h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon | \right)
        = 0 
        & , i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in\mathcal{K}_{21} 
    \end{split}
    \label{eq_3} \\
%
    H_{21} = H_{12} 
    &       
    \label{eq_4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Addition:
Until now I used the old eqnarray-environment. Using that, it looks nearly the way it should:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1} 
\leq h_i 
\leq \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_k + \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} \bar{s}_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1}
& , {} &    i \in \mathcal{I}_{21}
\label{eq:sf_height_fits_levelheight_i21}\\
%
\left( 1- \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2}\alpha_{ji}t_{jk}\right) 
\times \left( w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon -|w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon|\right) \qquad \qquad \quad
&    &      \nonumber \\
\qquad \times \left( h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon - | h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon |\right)
\geq 0
%
& ,  &      i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in\mathcal{K}_{21} \qquad \quad
\label{eq:sf_I22_not_in_new_I21} \\
H_{21} = H_{12}                             
&   &       
\label{eq:sf_def_H21}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Only problem: formular 3 is too wide, and formula numbers run out of text area (and eqnarray-environment is not the first choice).

Comment: Until now I used the old eqnarray-environment. With that, it looks nearly the way it should:

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses `aligned` environments inside the `align` environment. It loads the `\mathtools` package (and its `\smashoperator` macro) to squeeze the space around the summation symbols. The third equation gets an additional line break and now spans three lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{align}
&\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1}} 
   s_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1} 
   \leq h_i \leq 
   \smashoperator{\sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}}} 
   s_{ik} \tilde{h}_k + 
   \smashoperator{\sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1}} 
   \bar{s}_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1},
   \quad i\in\mathcal{I}_{21} \label{eq_1} \\[2ex]
%
&\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{l=K_{21}+1}^{K_{22}}}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\alpha_{lk} (s_{il} + \bar{s}_{il}) (1+\varepsilon) 
    + w_i + 
   \smashoperator{\sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2}} 
   \alpha_{ji} (s_{jk} + \bar{s}_{jk}) w_j\\
  &\geq (1 + \varepsilon)(1-s_{ik}-\bar{s}_{ik})
    ,\quad  i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in \mathcal{K}_{22}
  \end{aligned} 
    \label{eq_2} \\[2ex]
%
&\begin{aligned}   
  &\biggl( 1- \smashoperator{\sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2}}
          \alpha_{ji}t_{jk}\biggr)
   \times \biggl( w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon -
   \abs[\Big]{w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon}
   \biggr) \times \dotsb \\
  &\quad\dotsb\times\biggl( h_i + 
   \smashoperator{\sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2}} 
   \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon - 
   \abs[\Big]{ h_i + 
   \smashoperator{\sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2}} 
   \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon } 
   \biggr)
= 0,\\
  &\qquad\quad i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in\mathcal{K}_{21} 
\end{aligned} \label{eq_3} \\[2ex]
%
&H_{21} = H_{12}       
\label{eq_4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) ... i prepare almost the same solution, but I'm stuck in the definition of `\abs`. for some reason, doesn't work as i expected. by looking at your solution, i am looking for the cause of its operation :-)

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks. :-) The `\abs` macro is defined via the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro that's provided by the `mathtools` package. (The `mathtools` package also loads the `amsmath` package automatically.) The `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` method allows for explicit sizing of the vertical bars, via `\abs[\Big]{...}`.

Comment: thank you. meanwhile i resort my problems with `\abs` (oh me, how stupid the mistake  ... :-( ). due to small differences between my and  proposition, i will publish mine (soon).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

with combination of `align` and `multlined` environments from `mathtools`. i also will not use `\cdot` for multiplications (it is self understanding that terms in braces are multiplied):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&   \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1}
        \leq h_i \leq
    \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_k
    + \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} \bar{s}_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1},
     \qquad  i \in \mathcal{I}_{21}
    \label{eq_1}        \\[1em]
%
&   \begin{multlined}[0.7\linewidth]
    \sum_{l=K_{21}+1}^{K_{22}} \alpha_{lk}(s_{il} + \bar{s}_{il})
    (1 + \varepsilon) + w_i    \\
    + \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2} \alpha_{ji}(s_{jk} + \bar{s}_{jk}) w_j
        \geq (1 + \varepsilon)(1-s_{ik}-\bar{s}_{ik}),
    \qquad i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in \mathcal{K}_{22}
    \end{multlined}
    \label{eq_2}        \\[1em]
%
&   \begin{multlined}[0.7\linewidth]
        \biggl( 1- \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2}\alpha_{ji}t_{jk}\biggr)
            \biggl( w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon -
            \abs*{w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon}\biggr) \dotsm  \\
    \dotsm \biggl( h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l
        - H_{12} - \varepsilon - \abs[\bigg]{h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk}
        \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon }\biggr) = 0,    \\
        i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in\mathcal{K}_{21}
    \end{multlined}
    \label{eq_3}    \\[1em]
%
&    H_{21} = H_{12}
    \label{eq_4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't fit completely. I would like to left-align the first line of a multiline formula (is ok here). And I want to have the commas as alignment points, so that the (last line of a multi-line) formular is right aligned, the comma is centered and the variable declarations are left aligned and look like they were in one column.

Comment: @Juli: well, than my answer is not for you. i only suggest a solution in accordance to my taste, which apparently differ from yours. happy tex-ing!

Comment: @Mico, ups, this is mistake of course. now i notice that at copying of code i lost `\end{document}` :-(. now are all corrected! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `aligned` instead of `split`. Is this what you are after?

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{aligned}
    \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1} 
        \leq h_i 
        \leq \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_k 
             + \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} \bar{s}_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1}
    & ,     i \in \mathcal{I}_{21}
    \end{aligned}
    \label{eq_1} \\
%
    \begin{aligned}
        \sum_{l=K_{21}+1}^{K_{22}} \alpha_{lk} (s_{il} + \bar{s}_{il}) \left( 1 + \varepsilon \right) 
            + w_i + \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2} \alpha_{ji} (s_{jk} + \bar{s}_{jk}) w_j
    &   \\
        \geq (1 + \varepsilon)(1-s_{ik}-\bar{s}_{ik})
    & ,  i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in \mathcal{K}_{22}
    \end{aligned} 
    \label{eq_2} \\
%
    \begin{aligned}   
        \left( 1- \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2}\alpha_{ji}t_{jk}\right) 
            \cdot \left( w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon -|w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon|\right) \cdot  \ldots 
        & \\
        \ldots \cdot \left( h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon - 
        | h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon | \right)
        = 0 
        & , i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in\mathcal{K}_{21} 
    \end{aligned}
    \label{eq_3} \\
%
    H_{21} = H_{12} 
    &       
    \label{eq_4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you want to right-align all equations, you should provide a explicit alignments points (`&`). Separately, what's the purpose of encasing the first equation in an `aligned` environment?

Comment: It doesn't fit completely. I would like to left-align the first line of a multiline formula. And I want to have the commas as alignment points, so that the (last line of a multi-line) formular is right aligned, the comma is centered and the variable declarations are left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more along the lines of what you are looking for. I was able to split up the last equation in the middle of the parentheses (using $\left.$ and $\right.$), and I opted to use horizontal spacing to achieve your indentation.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   & \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1} 
        \leq h_i 
        \leq \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}} s_{ik} \tilde{h}_k 
             + \sum_{k=K_1+1}^{K_{21}-1} \bar{s}_{ik} \tilde{h}_{k+1}
    & , & i \in \mathcal{I}_{21}
    \label{eq_1} \\
%
   \begin{split}
       & \sum_{l=K_{21}+1}^{K_{22}} \alpha_{lk} (s_{il} + \bar{s}_{il}) \left( 1 + \varepsilon \right) 
            + w_i + \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2} \alpha_{ji} (s_{jk} + \bar{s}_{jk}) w_j
    \\
       & \kern 2cm \geq (1 + \varepsilon)(1-s_{ik}-\bar{s}_{ik})
    \end{split} 
    & , & i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in \mathcal{K}_{22}
    \label{eq_2} \\
%
   \begin{split}   
        & \left( 1- \sum_{j=I_1+1}^{I_2}\alpha_{ji}t_{jk}\right) 
            \cdot \left( w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon -|w_i - \frac{1}{m+2} - \varepsilon|\right) \cdot  \ldots 
        \\
        & \kern 2cm \ldots \cdot \left( h_i + \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon - 
        | h_i + \right.
        \\
        & \kern 3.85cm \left. \sum_{l=K_1+1}^{K_2} \alpha_{lk} \tilde{h}_l - H_{12} - \varepsilon | \right)
        = 0 
    \end{split}
    & , & i \in \mathcal{I}_{22}, k \in\mathcal{K}_{21} 
    \label{eq_3} \\
%
    & H_{21} = H_{12}       
    \label{eq_4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]